# Converting a number to Mexican peso letters

Tags: javascript, java, numbers

I have a problem statement, where I need to convert a mexican peso in numeric format(say 213.14) to mexican peso word format (DOSCIENTOS TRECE PESOS 14/100 M.N.) . Is there any library to achieve this in java or javascript.

Comment: after Trump election, no more mexican libraries are available worldwide

Comment: @quirimmo I assume that is a joke ... but I think SO should stay neutral on politics ...

Comment: @JonasWilms of course that was a joke

Comment: Take a look on [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25924949/number-to-word-conversion-in-java)